How to test offer codes (discount for subscription) in TestFlight?
I'm using
setup({ storekitMode: "STOREKIT2_MODE" });

But the problem is:
When trying to purchase a subscription directly, the sandbox environment works correctly, and I'm not charged (and thesandbox account is detected) and the same is with in all other cases (getting receipts, getting previous purchases), so everything works for sandbox account. EXCEPT offer activation. When trying to do it, it tries to activate the code using original Apple ID and tries to charge, but OK, I will just set a low price to test it. The problem is that the offer of activation is for Real Apple ID and all other environments is for sandbox accounts, so they are not synced, and I can't get receipt for purchase.
Logging out from the sandbox account and testing on TestFlight does not work, because in dev mode or in TestFlight environment it is sandbox anyway, so how can I test this scenario?

You can't really test offer codes outside of production environment,
However, when a user redeems an offer code, it creates a transaction just as if they made a purchase within or outside your app. To test offer code redemption, you can simply test this case when user buys a subscription via subscription management sheet that was opened in your app. And if your app can handle this case, then it will most likely handle offer codes the same way.
I shared this workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78995032/26425221
Maybe that will help your case.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

Thanks for the advice.
My original thought was that copying and pasting answers is not a good idea, so I added a link to the original answer.
Just added essential details.

Indeed, sometimes copy-pasting is not ideal. If the answer is 100% the same as for the other question, it is better to mark the question as a duplicate. But if the questions are not the same, it is wise to copy the relevant part from that answer - even tailor it to fit this question. You can find how to quote properly here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes
